# I have written api in php and again I am consuming my api in php, but delete method is not working

Tags: php, api

I have written api in php and consuming that api in php to make crud operations, but delete method is not working.

}

else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE'){

```
$del_id = $_GET["issuse_id"];

$url = 'http://192.168.0.82/ITS/Controller/issues'. $del_id;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response_json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data=json_decode($response_json, true);
return $data;
```

Comment: <td><a href="issues.php?del_id=<?php echo $row['issuse_id'];?>">delete</a></td>

Comment: Could you please further explain what you mean by the delete method is not working. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: <td><a href="issues.php?del_id=<?php echo $row['issuse_id'];?>">delete</a></td>

Comment: Are you missing the closing brace `}` for your `else if`

Answer (score 1):

From your post, I would guess that the issue you are having is likely due to wrong concatenation.

This line here:

```
$url = 'http://192.168.0.82/ITS/Controller/issues'. $del_id;
```

should instead be

```
$url = 'http://192.168.0.82/ITS/Controller/issues?del_id='. $del_id;
```

Comment: What's the difference there?

Comment: $url = 'http://192.168.0.82/ITS/Controller/issues/'. $del_id;   tried this also not working

Comment: @JonathonK the trailing slash.

Comment: @mahendra1145 kindly note the difference in the two, if this didn't work, could you please add the error message you're getting to your question?

Comment: @JonathonK I've just updated the answer based on new information the OP provided in the comments.